# Cannot implicitly Convert type to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to hard code some data for testing but can't seem to get this to work properly.  I'm sure that I am missing something simple.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetClusterAnswers(int clusterId, int sectionId)
{
    contractorId = UserInfo.targetCompanyID;
    var questions = await CommonClient.GetGeneralQandAsBySection(sectionId, contractorId);
    var selectedQuestion = questions.FirstOrDefault(q => q.QuestionClusterID == clusterId);
    int? questionid = selectedQuestion.QuestionID;

    QuestionsWithPairedAnswers question = new QuestionsWithPairedAnswers();
    question.QuestionID = questionid;
    question.vchQuestionText = selectedQuestion.vchQuestionText;
    question.vchTextElementOneHeader = selectedQuestion.vchTextElementOneHeader;
    question.vchTextElementTwoHeader = selectedQuestion.vchTextElementTwoHeader;

    question.Answers = new PairedAnswerTypes()
    {
        QuestionID = question.QuestionID,
        PairedTextElementAnswerID = 1,
        ContractorID = contractorId,
        vchTextElementOne = "ABC",
        vchTextElementTwo = "School Teachers"
    };
    return Json(question, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here are my models:

```
public class QuestionsWithPairedAnswers
{
    [Key]
    public int? QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string vchQuestionText { get; set; }
    public string vchTextElementOneHeader { get; set; }
    public string vchTextElementTwoHeader { get; set; }
    public List<PairedAnswerTypes> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class PairedAnswerTypes
{
    public int PairedTextElementAnswerID { get; set; }
    public int? QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int ContractorID { get; set; }
    public string vchTextElementOne { get; set; }
    public string vchTextElementTwo { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionsWithPairedAnswers Question { get; set; }
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What line do you get the error on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Answers` property inside `QuestionsWithPairedAnswers` is a `List<PairedAnswerTypes>` but in the following line:

```
question.Answers = new PairedAnswerTypes()
```

you try to set it to a `PairedAnswerTypes`.

Change it to:

```
question.Answers = new List<PairedAnswerTypes>
{
    new PairedAnswerTypes()
    {
        QuestionID = question.QuestionID,
        PairedTextElementAnswerID = 1,
        ContractorID = contractorId,
        vchTextElementOne = "ABC",
        vchTextElementTwo = "School Teachers"
    }
}
```

This way you put the new answer ***inside a new `List`*** as required by the property.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in this line:

```
question.Answers = new PairedAnswerTypes()
        {
            QuestionID = question.QuestionID,
            PairedTextElementAnswerID = 1,
            ContractorID = contractorId,
            vchTextElementOne = "ABC",
            vchTextElementTwo = "School Teachers"

        };
```

question.Answers is a `List` of `PairedAnswerTypes` and you assigning it a single `PairedAnswerTypes`, you can change this assignment to a list initializiation and assignment:

```
question.Answers = new List<PairedAnswerTypes> {
    new PairedAnswerTypes()
        {
            QuestionID = question.QuestionID,
            PairedTextElementAnswerID = 1,
            ContractorID = contractorId,
            vchTextElementOne = "ABC",
            vchTextElementTwo = "School Teachers"

        }
};
```